# Replace all column values based on another dataframe's index

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to map the values of one df column with values in another one.

First df contains football match results:

```
Date|HomeTeam|AwayTeam

2009-08-15|0|2
2009-08-15|18|15
2009-08-15|20|10
```

Second df contains teams and has only one column:

```
TeamName

Arsenal
Bournetmouth
Chelsea
```

The end result is the first df with matches but with team names instead of numbers in "HomeTeam" and "AwayTeam". The numbers in the first df mean indexes of the second one.

I've tried ".replace":

```
for item in matches.HomeTeam:
    matches = matches.replace(to_replace = matches.HomeTeam[item], value=teams.TeamName[item])
```

It did replace the values for some items (~80% of them), but ignored the other ones. I could not find a way to replace the other values.

Please let me know what I did wrong and how this can be fixed. Thanks!

Comment: maybe firstly you just change team numbers to team names using `map()` function: `df['col'] = df['col'].map({"1":"Chelsea", "2":"Real Madrid"})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try using `applymap`:

```
df[['HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam']] = df[['HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam']].applymap(lambda x: teams['TeamName'].tolist()[x])
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Output will be as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `teams` is also a DataFrame, something like:

```
teams = pd.DataFrame(data=[['Team_0'], ['Team_1'], ['Team_2'], ['Team_3'],
    ['Team_4'], ['Team_5'], ['Team_6'], ['Team_7'], ['Team_8'],
    ['Team_9']], columns=['TeamName'])
```

but you failed to include the index in the provided sample (actually, in
both samples).

Then my proposition is:

```
matches.set_index('Date')\
    .applymap(lambda id: teams.loc[id, 'TeamName'])\
    .reset_index()
```